# Wrong hyphenation with LY1 font ecoding?

Tags: hyphenation, font-encodings

[Here](http://www.tug.org/yandy/ly1.htm) I found the statement that no special hyphenation patterns are needed with LY1 font encoding.
Yet I stumbled upon different hyphenation in connection with non-letters (such as quotation marks) in utf8 input:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}
\def\foo{Michelsberg „Michelsberg Michelsberg“ }
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\foo\foo\foo\foo\foo\foo\foo Michelsberg!
Michelsberg, \foo Michelsberg? \foo\foo\foo Michelsberg.
\end{document}
```

One instance of a hyphenation `Michelsber-g“` occurs in the output.
With other encodings (e.g. T1), only the correct hyphenations (Mi-chels-berg) are used (or even tried as a look into the log shows).
Is there a way to systematically prevent this problem with LY1?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use LY1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The German closing quotes (English opening quotes) are in position octal 223 in LY1, whereas T1 has an uppercase letter (Ş) with a corresponding lowercase. Thus the double quote character participates in hyphenation because it has a non zero `\lccode`. A hyphenation `ber-g` is surely acceptable mid word and, as far as TeX is concerned, the `g` is followed by another letter.

You solve *this* issue by adding

```
\AtBeginDocument{\lccode'223=0 }
```

to your preamble.

There are probably other characters that need the same treatment: all punctuation characters that are in different position in LY1 with respect to T1; also the `\lccode` and `\uccode` vectors should be updated for letters in different positions.

I've always been suspicious about LY1, to tell you the truth.

Comment: That sounds very plausible (though `ber-g` should only be acceptable midword if followed by a vowel or possibly liquida, though even these may occur in composita with `berg-`)